# Initialize parameter from array

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I have a parameterised module whose `SEED` value has to change depending on the `WIDTH` parameter, where the seed values have to be hard-coded.

```
module Module;

parameter WIDTH = 8;

integer seeds [31:0] = {'hC, 'h1E, 'h39, 'h7E, /* ... */};
localparam SEED = seeds[WIDTH];

endmodule
```

This doesn't work, It's clear I'm trying to use the unpacked array in the wrong context.

```
Unable to bind parameter seeds[WIDTH] in module Module
```

How else can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

After adjusting the post to compile with the truncated 4-element array, Questa shows:

```
** Error: testbench.sv(): Parameter value must be constant.
```

Parameters and localparams can't accept variable values.
Integer is a variable type, it can change at run time.
Parameters must be known an compile time.

This compiles without warnings:

```
module Module;

parameter WIDTH = 1;

parameter integer seeds[4]  = {4'hC, 8'h1E, 8'h39, 8'h7E};

localparam SEED = seeds[WIDTH];

initial  
  $display("SEED = %0h",SEED);

endmodule
```

Questa Produces:

```
# vsim -voptargs=+acc=npr
# run -all
# SEED = 1e
```

This has an array of 4 hex values, and uses index 1 (WIDTH==1) as an argument to seeds.

Comment: I used the ellipsis comment to indicate that I'd truncated the full list of 32 values, that's common notation as far as I'm aware